# Facebook Embeded post will not render in safari

Tags: facebook, iframe, safari

Hello I have build a website and i have a facebook post embeded in it like so

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fvitrina.bg%2Fposts%2Fpfbid02EWp2MPqbUQ2DrYVkRinegLm2ae1yE6MUbnrypM6D5cV64zt2wG5zej5ExryG6VSil&show_text=true&width=500" width="100%" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

I have searched for this problem but I could not find any solution on the internet.

The Problem is that is working in firefox and chrome, but on safari mobile (iphone 11) does not render.

My website:

[Vitrina.bg](https://vitrina.bg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* not be a catch all solution, but it's what solved our issue.

We had taken the embed code from [Facebook's own documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/), and they specify to use https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2 as the path to their SDK.

This appears to be out of date.

When we updated the link to https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0, our embedded Facebook posts began appearing in Safari.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I guess you may check for the ios version on your iPhone. The current problem is that your iPhone safari in the newest version of ios 15 has feature security on the Safari setting.

So because of that feature, You must check Privacy & Security on your setting safari.

**Setting > (find) Safari > (find) Privacy & Security > (try to turn off) Hide Ip from Tracker.**

Above, Good luck to you. glhf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding the below meta tag will fix your problem:

```
  <meta
      httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="frame-src https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fvitrina.bg%2Fposts%2Fpfbid02EWp2MPqbUQ2DrYVkRinegLm2ae1yE6MUbnrypM6D5cV64zt2wG5zej5ExryG6VSil&show_text=true&width=500"
    />
```