# Facebook iFrame embed working on desktop but not mobile (iOS)?

Tags: html, iframe, mobile, embed

*My first post - sorry if nooby or wrong*

Used facebooks basic iFrame embed (my page is included):

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDqaI.png)

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Frobinhoodafcjuniors%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

Works on desktop website as you can see here here - https://www.robinhoodathletic.co.uk/news

Try the above link on iOS mobile and its just blank!

Excuse the website, just a quick set up for a local team using Wix!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly are you trying to achieve and can you please post the code directly inside the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey @IngoSteinke what i'm trying to achieve is the facebook social feed you can see on the desktop site delivered by iFrame but it's not appearing on mobile for some strange reason? Will add the code now

Comment: @IngoSteinke <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Frobinhoodafcjuniors%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>

Comment: Found the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679240/facebook-embeded-post-will-not-render-in-safari