# Facebook embeded live iframe not starting on safari

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

I will make it easy to understand, thank you in advance for your time and support

If you follow the steps below:

1 - Go to a live on facebook, Press more options, then Press Embed

[image]

2 - Copy the code

[image]

3 - Paste it into the website

4 - And, finally, if you open it in Safari mobile, **it would not start**.

My thought is that there might be something wrong with iFrame's `allow` attribute because if I try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74542146/14714168), the live starts.

I think there should be a way to solve it because if I copy the `src` of the iFrame and open it in a new tab (safari mobile) the live starts with no issue (even without the solution from linked answer).

Below is the iFrame Facebook generates:

```
<iframe src="URL_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK" width="560" height="314" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: There will likely be an error message in the console or safari just does not allow autoplay on embedded videos

Comment: On iPhone autoplay doesn't work in Google either, but If I open it in fullscreen mode it starts. I think I should find a way to see if there is any error in the console